# How to return the result of an Async Operation in AsyncTask doInBackground()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to make a server request call in a `doInBackground()` block of an `AsyncTask`.

The problem is that my server call is performed by an async function using a callback.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

        ServerLoader.getSharedInstance().get(url, 
            new new AsyncCallback<GetResult<Long>>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(GetResult<Long> result) {
              Long myResult = result.getValue();
            }

        );

        // return ??; How do I make the return?
     }

 }
```

**How do I get the return value from the async function call?**

Comment: don't use an asynctask, then, your call is already being played on a background thread.

Comment: I need it to be done on the background thread and update the UI after the call.

Comment: yes. that's what your callback is for.

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: you don't need this asynctask. call your `ServerLoader` method on the UI thread, it will take care of making the async call, and put your UI stuff in `onSuccess(GetResult<Long> result)`. Also, you could ask whoever wrote the `ServerLoader` class.

Comment: This is not a real answer/comment to your question but I would highly advise you to use RxJava/RxAndroid instead of AsyncTask. For more info, check out this talk: https://newcircle.com/s/post/1744/2015/06/29/learning-rxjava-for-android-by-example

Comment: @njzk2 Android reports me an error when I do network connections on the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

look at this schema, it helps me to understand AsyncTask
[image]

Comment: i wish someone showed me this when i was first learnt asynctask

Comment: This is true, but this does not answer my question on how I have to synchronize the async method in onInBackground?

Comment: i think that you must use get() to synchronize it.
try this classExtendsAsyncTask.execute().get();

Answer (score 0):

onPostExecute is where AsyncTask posts code to the UI if this is what you're asking.

```
new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");


private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
     return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
     // set image for ImageView
     mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
 }
```

}

Comment: How does this belong to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Since your server call is already performed in an asynchronous manner, you don't need to call it in `doInBackground()`, just use the facilities your server communication solution provides.

If you're trying to update a UI element with result data and get the `must be called from main thread`, you need to manually post your result-handling logic to UI *AKA main* thread like this:

```
ServerLoader.getSharedInstance().get(url, 
    new new AsyncCallback<GetResult<Long>>() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(GetResult<Long> result) {
        final Long myResult = result.getValue();
        // .post() on a view is what sends stuff to UI thread
        txtView.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                txtView.setText("" + myResult);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

If you're **absolutely set** on proxying your `ServerLoader` calls with `AsyncTask`, you can implement a dirty shim like this:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected CountDownLatch mLatch = null;
    protected Long mResult = null;
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        if (urls == null || urls.length = 0) {
            return null;
        }

        mLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        ServerLoader.getSharedInstance().get(url[0], 
            new new AsyncCallback<GetResult<Long>>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                // leave the result null
                mLatch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(GetResult<Long> result) {
                mResult = result.getValue();
                mLatch.countDown();
            }

        );

        // the thread that DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground()
        // gets executed on will wait till it hears from ServerLoader
        mLatch.await();
        return mResult;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // here you get the result
    }

}
```